# didFinishLaunching is never called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I created a new window-based project and couldn't figure out why it wasn't doing anything. Eventually I put an NSLog right after didFinishLaunching and it's never logged when I run it.  Here is all of the code I have written:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSLog(@"didFinishLaunching");

    // Get the device object and turn proximity monitoring on
    UIDevice *d = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    [d setProximityMonitoringEnabled:YES];

    // Get the NSNotificationCenter object
    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

    // Sign up to receive notifications when the proximity state changes
    [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(proximityChanged:) name:UIDeviceProximityStateDidChangeNotification object:d];
    NSLog(@"Observing...");

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;

}

- (void)proximityChanged:(NSNotification *)note {

    // Print out the changes of proximity state
    NSLog(@"Proximity Changed: %d", [[note object] proximityState]);

}
```

That's the entirety of what I've written and nothing is logged when I run it on the simulator or on my device.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you are talking about Application Delegate. The obvious reason - **your object is not set as an application delegate**.

Looking at Apple documentation there is quite a few ways to accomplish it:

1. Remove application delegate binding in Interface Builder (.xib file for the window)
2. Set 4th parameter of UIApplicationMain in main.h to something else than nil.

**Check you nib file in Interface Builder and see if the App Delegate is setup.**

*Reference to documentation*
[Core Application Design](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html)

> The application delegate is a custom object that you provide at
>   application launch time, usually by embedding it in your application’s
>   main nib file. The primary job of this object is to initialize the
>   application and present its window onscreen. The UIApplication object
>   also notifies this object when specific application-level events
>   occur, such as when the application needs to be interrupted (because
>   of an incoming message) or moved to the background (because the user
>   tapped the Home button).

---

> The fourth parameter identifies the class of the application delegate.
>   The application delegate is responsible for managing the high-level
>   interactions between the system and your custom code. Specifying nil
>   tells UIKit that the application delegate object is located in the
>   application’s main nib file (which is the case for applications built
>   using the Xcode templates).

Answer (score 1):

Try removing doing a Build/Clean All Targets, remove the Build/ directory and delete the app from the simulator and/or the device. Then run it again.

As another check, try logging something in `applicationDidBecomeActive:`. This method will be called whether on the initial launch or resuming from the background.